# Is it possible to overwrite existing data in .xlsx file with openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, python-3.x, openpyxl

Say I want to update som data in example1.xlsx.
Is this possible to do using openpyxl without having to save it as a new file?

Comment: xlsx is a zip file with xml files, images, and metadata files. you can unzip, modify xml files, repack directly.

Comment: This is essentially a restriction of the zip file format which does not support editing in place. So, no you cannot do this.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell you can open a workbook with openpyxl, modify some data, then save the workbook in place:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('path\\to\\workbook.xlsx')
c = wb['Sheet1']['A1']
c.value = 'hello'
wb.save('path\\to\\workbook.xlsx')
```

If you're saying that your workbook is too big to manipulate in this way, it looks as if you would have to open it in [read-only mode](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/optimized.html), manipulate the data as you read it in, and write it to a new workbook in [write-only mode](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/optimized.html#write-only-mode).

Comment: Why do I get a `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.` when I hit the `my_workbook.save(<filename>)` ?

Comment: Problem solved. The problem is with openpyxl reading workbooks with image data. This is a pre-existing problem that it loses image data when workbook being modified has image data beforehand and cannot be saved again.